# Error in loading the model.json in web application

Tags: node.js, json, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I am trying to load the model.json file (converted from python) and it is having the bin files as well. I have imported tfjs-node and tfjs but still getting the error as **\atrbtsjsonmodel.json does not exist: loading failed.**

Can someone help?

This is the code I have written -

```
const tf = require ('@tensorflow/tfjs')
const tfn = require ('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
```

```
async function loadModel(){

    const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem('atrbts\json\model.json');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    console.log("Model loaded")
}
```

Comment: You need to be using forward slashes `/` in the file name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my query , a small change but definitely useful! Now I am facing issue with dependencies but I will look into it.